# Serve external file on nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, server, wget

I want to deliver a external file from a nginx server, something like to wget a file and serve on try_files, something like this

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ http://externalurl.com/index.html;
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The `try_files` directive can only accept an internal URI as the last parameter.

However, you can also use a named location as the last parameter, and place your external URL there. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect;
}
location @redirect {
    return 302 http://externalurl.com/index.html;
}
```

Comment: This will redirect de url to http://externalurl.com/index.html or will keep my URL and serve the file  http://externalurl.com/index.html under the hood ? because i want to dynamically serve the external file on my current URL, in a node webserver i could download de file on the fly with fetch and serve it, but with nginx i dont know if this is possible

Comment: The above code will perform a redirect, if you want a reverse proxy, use: `proxy_pass` instead.